# Redirect URL in apache to another website for all paths except valid ones?

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to redirect everything that hits

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/invalidpath
```

To another website on another host.  BUT not if it's:

```
http://example.com/validpath
```

How do I do this with apache?

Answer (score 0):

You could make it with an **.htaccess** and the **Rewite module**.
First of all, activate the rewrite module:

- Ubuntu/Debian: `a2enmod rewrite; service apache2 restart`

After that, write a simple .htacces (or you can add these lines to the global configuration file, if you want):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-f
RewriteRule (.*) <defaultPage> [L]
```

1. Matches what you write after the slash

```
example.com/wrongpath
```

2. Check if that *file exists* on the server
3. If the file specified is not present, **rewrite to defaultPage**

```
example.com/defaultPage
```

I hope it can be helpful for you.